# Org-mode external links not working when exported to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, hyperlinks

I have 2 `.org` files:

```
// a.org contains the anchor
<<my_anchor>>

// b.org contains the link to my_anchor
[[file:a.org::my_anchor][My Link]]
```

When I click on the link in org-mode, it links correctly to the position of `my_anchor` in `a.org`. But when I export these 2 files to HTML, what I expect is:

```
// b.html
<a href="a.html#my_anchor">My Link</a>
```

What I got is:

```
// b.html
<a href="a.html">My Link</a>
```

I wonder how to correctly write an external link so that it works both in org-mode and in exported HTML.

Comment: What I get is `<a id="orgtarget1"></a>` in `a.html` and `<a href="a.html#MissingReference">My Link</a>` in `b.html`, which is marginally better, but not functional.  This org version 8.3.3.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the info, mine is 8.2.5. This looks promising, possibly it requires a special way to write the link in org mode, I wonder how.

Comment: It looks more like a bug to me - have you tried reporting it?

Comment: @AndrewSwann No, I haven't learnt how to report a bug. Actually I don't feel like investing more time on it for the moment. It seems not an important issue anyways.

Comment: @AndrewSwann It is a documentation bug. You find more details about that at the end of my answer below. I've filed a bug report.

Comment: Links to anchors within other org-files work (see my answer) but it is an experimental feature (see bottom of my answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string behind `::` is actually a *search*. In this context one understands the relevant comment in the source code of the function `org-html-link` in the library file `ox-html.el` (org 8.2.5).
It says:

```el
  ;; Add search option, if any.  A search option can be
  ;; relative to a custom-id or a headline title.  Any other
  ;; option is ignored.
```

So, you can either replace `my_anchor` by `#my_anchor` to form a custom-id or use a headline title starting with the character `*`.
In the second case don't include spaces after the `*`-character!

Linking **section headers** in other files **only works when you publish org-mode projects**. Org-mode projects are defined as members of the variable `org-publish-project-alist`. See the documentation of this variable and Section *13 Publishing* of the org-mode manual for the details.

Example:
file `a.org`:

```
* This is file a.org
  Some important notes.

* Second Section

* Section with a custom-id

  Some text before the custom-id

  <<#my-anchor>> Here we have the custom-id

  Some text behind the custom-id.
```

Text in file `b.org`:

```
* This is file b.org
  Some text.

* b.org contains the link to my_anchor
  [[file:a.org::#my_anchor][My Link to the custom-id]]

  [[file:a.org::*Second Section][My Link to the headline of the second section]]
```

Remark:
The reason that links to headers in other files only work with publishing is that they are fetched from `org-publish-cache` in `org-publish-resolve-external-fuzzy-link` which is used in `org-html-link`.

Section header links are actually numbered links, such as `sec-1`, `sec-2` and the section headers are translated to the numbers 1,2,... via an association list in the variable `org-publish-cache`.

---

**I consider this a documentation bug.** The html-export of links of section headers in other files is not mentioned in Section *13.1.6 Links between published files* of the org-mode manual. I can also not find any remark of the html-export of links to custom-id's across files in the manual.

I've just discovered these things through reading the source code.

---

This is what I got as an answer to my bug-report:

```
Thank you for the report.

Unfortunately, this feature is very experimental, and actually quite
buggy. It's not ready for prime time, and therefore not documented.
```